# Get Row Totals for Dynamically Created Pivoted Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

In PostgreSQL I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cross_table (brand varchar(10), gender varchar(10), sales int);

INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Nike', 'Male', 10);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Nike', 'Male', 20);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Adidas', 'Woman', 20);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Nike', 'Male', 10);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Adidas', 'Woman', 30);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Puma', 'Woman', 40);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Puma', 'Male', 10);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Nike', 'Male', 20);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Puma', 'Woman', 10);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Adidas', 'Woman', 20);
```

And then I run this query to get brand as rows, gender as columns ans sales as value:

```
with main_query as (    
    SELECT  brand,
            GROUPING(brand) AS "brand_grouping",
            gender,
            GROUPING(gender) AS "gender_grouping",
            sum(sales) AS "sales"
    FROM    cross_table
    GROUP BY ROLLUP (brand, gender)
),  
second_query AS (
    SELECT  brand,
            brand_grouping,
            cast(
                json_object_agg(
                  gender,
                  sales
                  ORDER BY gender DESC
                ) FILTER (WHERE gender_grouping = 0) AS jsonb) "gender",
            SUM(sales)  AS "sales"
    FROM main_query
    GROUP BY (brand, brand_grouping)
)

SELECT  brand,
        gender,
        sales
FROM    second_query
ORDER BY brand_grouping, brand
```

This would produce the following result:

| brand | gender | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| adidas | { "Woman": 70 } | 140 |
| nike | "Male": 60 | 120 |
| puma | "Male": 10, "Woman": 50 | 120 |
| NULL | NULL | 190 |

Please note: gender column is now in object but brackets won't show in the table view here on Stackoverflow.

This is fine, only problem is that it is missing row totals for the pivoted "gender" column. I can solve this hardcoded by changing last query to this:

```
SELECT  brand,
        CASE WHEN gender IS null THEN
            jsonb_build_object(
                'Woman', SUM(("gender"->>'Woman')::float8) OVER (),
                'Male', SUM(("gender"->>'Male')::float8) OVER ()
        ) ELSE "gender" END AS "gender",
        sales
FROM    second_query
ORDER BY brand_grouping, brand
```

Getting this result:

| brand | gender | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| adidas | {"Woman": 70} | 140 |
| nike | "Male": 60 | 120 |
| puma | "Male": 10, "Woman": 50 | 120 |
| NULL | "Male": 70, "Woman": 120 | 190 |

Which is correct but I need to do this dynamically without knowing the keys (Male/Woman) of "gender".

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: the results you talk about are not displayed. Please add the results in plain text, no picture.

Comment: @Edouard Thanks for noticing. Added now. There was a problem showing brackets in that table view so removed them. But please note that those Male/Woman values in gender columns are shown in my result output in brackets because they are a JSON object.

Comment: thanks @Marius. Just to understand your issue : why do you "need to do this dynamically without knowing the keys (Male/Woman) of 'gender'" ? Is there any other possible value in column gender that is not known before run time ?

Comment: @Edouard Yes, gender is an example column where it's values are pivoted to columns. In this example we know it is Male & Woman but the values in the column to pivot could be unknown so this needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT brand
     , jsonb_object_agg(gender, sales) AS gender
     , sum(sales) AS sales
  FROM (
SELECT brand
     , gender
     , sum(sales) AS sales
  FROM cross_table
 GROUP BY ROLLUP(brand), gender
) AS a
GROUP BY brand
```

Result :

| brand | gender | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | {"Male": 70, "Woman": 120} | 190 |
| Adidas | {"Woman": 70} | 70 |
| Nike | {"Male": 60} | 60 |
| Puma | {"Male": 10, "Woman": 50} | 60 |

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/95qf576r)

Comment: Vow, that is really nice and simple @Edouard.  So the  problem/solution is how to compose the group by & rollups correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Follow up question here if you want to try:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75028337/transpose-values-of-pivoted-table-to-rows

Comment: I've tried ... see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75028904/8060017)