# Transpose Values of Dynamically Created Pivoted Table to Rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

In PostgreSQL I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cross_table (brand varchar(10), gender varchar(10), sales int);

INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Nike', 'Male', 10);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Nike', 'Male', 20);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Adidas', 'Woman', 20);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Nike', 'Male', 10);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Adidas', 'Woman', 30);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Puma', 'Woman', 40);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Puma', 'Male', 10);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Nike', 'Male', 20);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Puma', 'Woman', 10);
INSERT INTO cross_table (brand, gender, sales) VALUES ('Adidas', 'Woman', 20);
```

Then I can run this query to get brand as rows, gender as columns and "Sum of Sales" and "Count of Sales" as values:

```
SELECT  brand,
        jsonb_object_agg(
            gender,
            json_build_object(
                'Sum of Sales', "Sum of Sales",
                'Count of Sales', "Count of Sales"
            )
        ) AS gender,
        SUM("Sum of Sales")  AS "Sum of Sales",
        SUM("Count of Sales")  AS "Count of Sales"
FROM (
    SELECT  brand,
            gender,
            sum(sales) AS "Sum of Sales",
            count(sales) AS "Count of Sales"
    FROM cross_table
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(brand), gender
) AS a
GROUP BY brand
```

This would produce the following result:

| brand | gender | Sum of Sales | Count of Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | {"Male": {"Sum of Sales": 70,"Count of Sales": 5},"Woman": {"Sum of Sales": 120, "Count of Sales": 5}} | 190 | 10 |
| adidas | {"Woman": {"Sum of Sales": 70,"Count of Sales": 3}} | 70 | 3 |
| nike | {"Male": {"Sum of Sales": 60, "Count of Sales": 4}} | 60 | 4 |
| puma | {"Male": {"Sum of Sales": 10,"Count of Sales": 1 }, "Woman": {"Sum of Sales": 50,"Count of Sales": 2}} | 60 | 3 |

But I would like to have the values as rows like this:

| brand | values | Male | Woman | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | Sum of Sales | 70 | 120 | 190 |
|  | Count of Sales | 5 | 5 | 10 |
| adidas | Sum of Sales |  | 70 | 70 |
|  | Count of Sales |  | 3 | 3 |
| nike | Sum of Sales | 60 |  | 60 |
|  | Count of Sales | 4 |  | 4 |
| puma | Sum of Sales | 10 | 50 | 60 |
|  | Count of Sales | 1 | 2 | 3 |

I've looked at two approaches:

*1. Putting the values into an object like this:*

```
json_build_object(
  'Sum of Sales', SUM(sales),
  'Count of Sales', COUNT(sales)
) as "Values"
```

And then in some way "expanding" them as rows under "Values" column.

*2. Using unnest in some way but unsure about that approach.*

Important requirement:
*The values in brand and gender are unknown so the values from brand (nike, etc) and gender (male, etc) are generated dynamically.*

Does anyone know how to do this?

For context; this is a continuation of this question:

[Get Row Totals for Dynamically Created Pivoted Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75015862/get-row-totals-for-dynamically-created-pivoted-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Splitting the resulting rows in 2 subrows in not a big deal :**

```
SELECT  brand,
        label,
        jsonb_object_agg(
            gender,
            json_build_object(label, total)
        ) AS gender,
        SUM(total)  AS "Total"
FROM (
    SELECT  brand,
            gender,
            sum(sales) :: integer AS total,
            'Sum of Sales' AS label
    FROM cross_table
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(brand), gender
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  brand,
            gender,
            count(sales) :: integer,
            'Count of Sales'
    FROM cross_table
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(brand), gender
) AS a
GROUP BY brand, label
ORDER BY brand, label ;
```

**2. Splitting the resulting columns in 2 or more subcolumns may be more touchy :**

*2.A Static list of gender values*

If gender has only two values "male" and "woman" then :

```
CREATE TYPE gender AS (male integer, woman integer) ;

SELECT  brand,
        label,
        (jsonb_populate_record(null :: gender, jsonb_object_agg(lower(gender),total))).*,
        SUM(total)  AS "Total"
FROM (
    SELECT  brand,
            gender,
            sum(sales) :: integer AS total,
            'Sum of Sales' AS label
    FROM cross_table
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(brand), gender
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  brand,
            gender,
            count(sales) :: integer,
            'Count of Sales'
    FROM cross_table
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(brand), gender
) AS a
GROUP BY brand, label
ORDER BY brand, label ;
```

*2.B Dynamic list of gender values*

If the gender list of values may vary in time, then :

We need to dynamically create and update the composite type gender from a trigger on table `cross_table` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_cross_table ()
  RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  _columns text ;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT gender || ' integer', ',')
    INTO _columns
    FROM cross_table ;
  DROP TYPE IF EXISTS gender ;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE gender (' || _columns || '(' ;
  RETURN NULL ;
END ; $$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_cross_table AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF gender OR DELETE
  ON cross_table FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION trigger_cross_table() ;
```

The final query is the same :

```
SELECT  brand,
        label,
        (jsonb_populate_record(null :: gender, jsonb_object_agg(lower(gender),total))).*,
        SUM(total)  AS "Total"
FROM (
    SELECT  brand,
            gender,
            sum(sales) :: integer AS total,
            'Sum of Sales' AS label
    FROM cross_table
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(brand), gender
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  brand,
            gender,
            count(sales) :: integer,
            'Count of Sales'
    FROM cross_table
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(brand), gender
) AS a
GROUP BY brand, label
ORDER BY brand, label ;
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SbGJDEi9)

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering about your comment: "Splitting the resulting columns in 2 or more subcolumns may be more touchy". Why is that? Isn't your solution number 1 sufficient because all you need is "one union query per value function"? So if I also wanted "Avg of Sales" it would be 3 union queries etc.

Comment: The only problem I can see with number one is that "Sum of Sales" and "Count of Sales" key are duplicated: https://www.screencast.com/t/KVJs4V51Er

Comment: Solution 1 is mixing in one unique column 'gender' the results for 'male' and 'woman'. Solution 2 splits the results in 2 separated columns 'male' and 'woman' as you expect, and solution 3 do the same in a dynamic way with 2 or more columns according to the values in the 'gender' column of your table 'cross_table'. So solution 3 should provide the expected result.

Comment: Yes. But I think solution 1 is better, less complex and for my purpose simpler to handle in the client that will render this result. "gender" is basically an multi-level column with columns gender-male-"Sum of Sales", gender-woman-etc.